# Custom carousel with meta box data

Tags: metabox

I have a custom meta box carousel which I have working, The only problem im having is it is only looping through one picture, the same image is shown on the slides.

Can someone please point me in the correct direction please.

Thanks

```
$images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_agd_test_file_list', true );
if ( $images ) {
foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $img_full_url ) {
echo'<div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item">';
echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment_id );
echo'</div>';
echo '<div class="item">';
echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment_id );
echo'</div></div></div>';
}}
```

I know there is 4 images being held in the array but I can only get one to display in the cycle.

Comment: Are the images printed to the source of the page?

Comment: Your `HTML` is broken Look at line number `6` `div class="item">` missing `<`.

Comment: The images are printed on the page, well one is.

Comment: In the code it is there Sisir, must of missed it in the paste on here.